# How to add ActionCable to a ruby on rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

I am working in a project which has 3 separate parts - a ruby on rails engine, a ruby on rails application, and a frontend react application. I need to introduce websockets / ActionCable in the engine, and am not having any luck getting ActionCable running.

I have the following relevant files in the engine:

app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
  end
end
```

app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
  end
end
```

app/channels/fromserver_channel.rb

```
class FromServerChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel

  def subscribed
    stream_from "fromClient"
  end

  def receive(data)
    puts '----------'
    puts data
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "fromServer", data
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

config/environments/development.rb

```
require 'action_cable/engine'

Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true

  #specify the socket URI for ActionCable
  config.action_cable.url = "/cable"

  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/*/, /https:\/\/*/]
end
```

config/cable.rb

```
development:
  adapter: async
test:
  adapter: async
production:
  adapter: postgresql
```

config/routes.rb

```
require 'action_cable/engine'

RoundaboutEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
  # mount RoundaboutEngine::Engine => "/cable"
  scope controller: 'round_about' do
    get 'organizer' => :show
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.send(:draw) do
  mount RoundaboutEngine::Engine => '/' if RoundaboutEngine.draw_routes_in_host_app
end
```

The front end looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import channel from './cable';

const RoundAboutView = () => {
  const [displayText, setDisplayText] = useState('');

  const sendUpdate = (arg) => {
    channel.sending(arg);
  };

  return (
    ...
        Text:
        {` ${displayText}`}
    ...
  );
};

export default RoundAboutView;
```

```
import ActionCable from 'actioncable';

// const cable = ActionCable.createConsumer('wss://localhost:9292/cable');
const cable = ActionCable.createConsumer(`ws://${window.location.host}/cable`);

const channel = cable.subscriptions.create(
  { channel: 'FromServerChannel' },
  {
    connected() { },
    disconnected() {},
    received: (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    },
    sending(data) {
      this.perform('fromClient', { data });
    },
  },
);
export default channel;
```

The problem I am having is that Chrome says the websocket can't connect (`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9292/cable' failed`). In the terminal, when in routes.rb I mount /cable with ActionCable.server, I see the below:

```
"exception":{
  "type":"NoMethodError",
  "message":"undefined method `info' for nil:NilClass",
  "stack_trace":"NoMethodError(undefined method `info' for nil:NilClass)\n actioncable (5.2.6) lib/action_cable/connection/tagged_logger_proxy.rb:38:in `block in log'\n actioncable (5.2.6)
```

When I don't do that and instead mount /cable with the engine, I get an error that the route GET /cable doesn't exist.

I'm not able to move past this point and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or missing in the code. I've seen the example at https://github.com/palkan/engine-cable-app and wasn't able to take that example and make it work in my code. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem without an `Engine`? Without `React`? Without both?

Comment: Looking at [tagged_logger_proxy.rb:38](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.6/actioncable/lib/action_cable/connection/tagged_logger_proxy.rb#L38), (the line referenced by the stack trace) it seems `@logger` is nil. Maybe you need to define a logger in your `Engine`? Just a wild guess.